# Excel assign value to rows in column C where any rows in column A with the same value also has a value in column B

Tags: excel

I'm trying to figure out how to identify whether any dates in column A that share the same value also has a value in column B. if so, I want all values in column C for that date in column A to have a value of "yes", otherwise the value should be "no".

Example:

| A | B | C (expected result) | D (result so far) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-01-01 |  | No | No |
| 2023-01-01 |  | No | No |
| 2023-01-01 |  | No | No |
| 2023-01-01 |  | No | No |
| 2023-01-01 |  | No | No |
| 2023-01-01 |  | No | No |
| 2023-01-01 |  | No | No |
| 2023-01-08 |  | Yes | No |
| 2023-01-08 |  | Yes | No |
| 2023-01-08 |  | Yes | No |
| 2023-01-08 |  | Yes | No |
| 2023-01-08 | There is text here | Yes | Yes |
| 2023-01-08 |  | Yes | No |
| 2023-01-08 |  | Yes | No |
| 2023-01-08 |  | Yes | No |

My formula so far is as follows:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((A:A = A2)*(ISTEXT(C2)))
```

As you can see in Column D, my result isn't what I'm expecting and I know the formula isn't quite right but I am unaware of the proper solution.

The solution must be flexible such that adding extra rows will work automatically and it cannot use Power Query or macros.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `COUNTIFS`:

```
=IF(COUNTIFS(A:A,A2,B:B,"<>")>0,"Yes","No")
```

[image]